# RGBDSLAM alternatives for Indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rgbdslamv2, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I've been assigned a project in which the robot has to generate the environment map and locate itself in it, all with a Kinect.

The problem is that I've found only solutions involving the Fuerte-based rgbdslam library (for instance, [this one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/build-a-ros-robot-with-slam-without-laser)) while I'm using Indigo.

Is there any alternative I can use with Indigo?

I know there's a rgbdslam_v2 for Hydro which seems can be used in Indigo, but I was wondering if are there more reliable solutions.

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226001/rgbdslam-alternatives-for-indigo/) by [Luca Cpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25870/luca-cpz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

RGBDSLAM works now with indigo. I used it a little (I don't know if all works) but it works for what I have done.

You can go to https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2 and select Branch indigo.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) with karma: 113 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luca Cpz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25870/luca-cpz/) on 2016-02-09**:
Thanks for your reply. In the meantime, I found out rtabmap_ros, what do you think about it as alternative?

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-03-18**:
Actually I'm using RTAB-Map, and it works really fine out of the box. It's very configurable according your needs.